# How do I get offline voice detection on my tablet running JB (4.1.1)?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, voice-recognition, offline

I just got myself a budget tablet (Halo Value) from "Swipe Telecom", and I was wondering how I can get offline speech recognition on it, since JB should support it.

My language is set to English (US), and I can't seem to find any option to download offline voice recognition files. I looked under `Settings > Language & input > Google voice typing settings` and it has just one option, to block offensive words. Under voice search settings, I have "speech output", "block offensive words" and "Hotword Detection".

Any ideas how to get offline voice recognition on the tab?

Answer (score 4):

There's a tutorial on [How to Activate Offline Voice Typing on Jelly Bean](http://jellybean-news.blogspot.de/2013/02/how-to-activate-offline-voice-typing-on.html) which you could follow. Here's an excerpt:

1. Open the *system settings* of the device.
2. Go to *language and placing.*
3. Make a tap on *voice search.*
4. Now do a tap on *Download ricon. VOC. offline.*
5. With a swype moved *All* tab and select your language, it will begin the download of the package.
6. Eventually the card *INSTALLED* will appear.

Now you should be able to use voice input in offline mode.

Just in case, here are several additional howtos:

- [How To: Enable Offline Voice Typing in All Jelly Bean Android Devices](http://temefy.com/how-to-enable-offline-voice-typing-in-all-jelly-bean-android-devices)
- [Download and Install Google Now with Voice Search (Stable Version) On Galaxy S3](http://pc-updates.blogspot.de/2012/08/download-and-install-google-now-with.html)

.

---

From the first "additional link", the description looks a bit different:

1. Go to *Settings*
2. Go to *Languages and Input*
3. Check if the language is selected as *English(US)*. If not, then set it.
4. In the *Inputs*, look if the option *Google Voice Typing* is checked. If not, then check it.
5. Select the *gear icon* beside the Google Voice Typing. This will take you to the voice typing settings.
6. In the *Choose Input Language*, uncheck automatic and select *English(US)*.
7. Below, in the *Download Offline Speech Recognition* option, select *English(US)*.
8. After the download completes, close the settings.
9. Go anywhere for typing, like Messaging.
10. Select the little *gear icon* in the bottom left area. This will give the option of selecting Voice Typing.
11. Speak out your words clearly and the device will type it out even if Internet Connection is Inactive.

You should be able to do this with other languages as well (e.g. *English(UK)*) -- just make sure they match in all places.

Comment: As I said in my question, my language is already set to English(US), and I have looked in those places, bit I don't have any option to download offline voice recognition files.

Also beside google voice typing, I have a settings icon and not a gears icon.

Comment: Not having a JB *phone*, I cannot check that currently. Will do so with my tablets at home. But AFAIR they all have the "gears" icon for settings. Apart from the icon used, shouldn't the link go to the same pages?

Comment: +1: I've got an S3 with JB 4.1.1, and the above instructions are accurate.

Comment: That's the problem, i saw that setting on several videos on youtube as well...but it isn't there on my tab. i don't know if it uses a different ROM or something, but the setting simply isn't there, and that's why I am looking for other methods

Comment: Maybe you could add a few details: 1) exact Android version (from *Settings->About*), 2) a link to device specifications (or anything coming close to that), 3) screenshots (or links to them, I'll integrate them then). This might help us to narrow things down. As techie007 already checked on 4.1.1, that's all I could have done (same version on my tabbies), so we can skip that for now.

Comment: Is there such an option on nexus 5 with kit kat?